# Jquery to get the url when clicking a link

Tags: jquery

In a page, I have a link as `N0016`

```
jQuery(".ms-listlink").click(function() {  alert($("a", this).attr("href"));  });
```

But here I am not able to get the alert.

```
[<div class=​"ms-vb  ms-vb-menuPadding itx" ctxname=​"ctx104" id=​"16" field=​"LinkTitle" perm=​"0x7fffffffffffffff" eventtype>​<a class=​"ms-listlink ms-draggable" onfocus=​"OnLink(this)​" href=​"http:​/​/​otsidemo:​11111/​sites/​Dev/​Satya/​_layouts/​15/​listform.aspx?P…6E430115DC12%7D&ID=16&ContentTypeID=0x0100A8CBE041E83BA346BCF4EB1F7DE540E7" onclick=​"EditLink2(this,104)​;​return false;​" target=​"_self" dragid=​"15" draggable=​"true">​N0016​</a>​</div>​]
```

Comment: That should work, try `$(this).children('a).attr('href');`

Comment: You're using in jQuery different class than this div has.

Comment: can we not use the class name for `a` tag?

Comment: if target is _self .. how can a click function work on a anchor tag.. it will go the other page rigth??

Comment: yes but before going to next page, I need to get the url..

Comment: make the taget  _blank and add`$(".ms-listlink").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); alert($("a", this).attr("href"));  });`

Comment: I can not change anything about the link..

Comment: Make sure you understand what `$("a", this)` means. It will give you all anchor elements that are *children* of the current element. But the current element already is your anchor, so `$(this)` should suffice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you want to check or alert attached link the you can use following example

step 1 : write following statement in html

```
<a href='www.google.com'>Click here</a>
```

step 2: write following satatement in js file

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery('a').click(function( e ){
      e.preventDefault();
         alert(jQuery(this).attr('href'));//return associated link.

    });


})
```

You can check example using this link - http://jsfiddle.net/Le8ewkj8/3/

Comment: what if there is more than one `a` tags. so clicking on one should get me the url

Comment: you can define id like <a id='abc'>click here</a>.After it you can call using jQuery('#abc').click(function(e){ //same content })

Answer (score 4):

Try this. Let me know what are your thoughts

```
$(function(){
    jQuery(document).on("click",".ms-listlink",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var el = jQuery(this);
      alert(el.attr("href"));
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You allready set your class on the link, and by this defination `$("a",this)` you say that "find a sub link in my link" and it is really absurd :) everybody can make mistakes like this as tired. and you have to avoid the event to do somethings by `preventDefault()`

```
jQuery(".ms-listlink").click(function(e) {  e.preventDefault();  alert($(this).attr("href"));  });
```